# Generic type condition is lost when using typeof

Tags: typescript

When using the type of the first argument of one function as the type of the first argument in another function typescript loses the generic type conditions. Is there a way to make example2 use the same type as example by reference example's argument type.

```
const example = <T,>(args: {a: T, b: T extends number ? number : never}) => {
  console.log(args.a, args.b)
}

example({a: 12, b: 13}) // works as expected
example({a: 'foo', b: 13}) // warning as expected

const example2 = (args: Parameters<typeof example>[0]) => {
  console.log(args)
}

example2({a: 12, b: 13}) // warning, does not work as expected
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOMC8MA8AKgDQB8AFEgE4DmEAXDAN5KMkwBGb8CUcYAEwgwwAVxQc4VGAH4R4ydMZg4ANykBfAJS5SzAFAwYoSCCwA6DCBqVaEc0mIxqdcxy36N+-YlSY45CyMAIwATE5cMMEAzNowAPTxMADuIFQA1sJIwohocMB8Aj7I6FiBrDAA5ACeIJURIbE6iSnUYACWYDTOOQh5BXBF+ibQPH5YobgwtnSMAArUqHB8VBD4UNV5IABmY6VwpADaAAwAujo4ekyGxuAQZnCW1jMQHl7F43Ch5SHhnI1xFrJNqdGhOAQgODCMAgWCpDI9Hj9Qr6IA)

Comment: Not entirely sure how useful this is, while instead, you could just declare a typing and share it amongst your functions                                                                        
(`type testType = (arg1: string, arg2: string) => void;                                                       const test: testType = (arg1, arg2) => console.log('hi');)`

Comment: That's what I'll probably end up doing. I was curious why the other way doesn't work though.

Comment: What would you expect `Parameters<typeof example>[0]` to be? Can you name that type? Do you expect an unbound generic to appear somehow, even though `example2` is not generic? If you want `example2` do be generic you have to make it so explicitly and then you could use an instantiation expression on `example` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WY5GzW).  So, uh, what's the question here? I don't see you asking a specific question; please [edit] to ask one, so we can answer it.

Comment: Yes I guess I was expecting the unbound generic to appear somehow even though example2 is not generic. It seems surprising to me how generics work when they are being inferred. Thanks for the playground link that essentially answers the question.